# alert the contents of an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
<input id="ssc_BB_0" class="ssc_lrBuyBtn" type="button" value="Buy" onclick="ssc.buyClicked(0,2)">
```

I don't have direct access to the ssc.buyClicked function and was wondering if it is possible to alert what that might be so I may modify it to my needs. I have tried...

```
alert(ssc.buyClicked.asString());
```

but that did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for toString, rather than asString ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might want the `toString` method here.

Also, it might be useful to note that most modern web browsers have Developer tools that will allow you to inspect the scripts executed on a page. Pressing F12 will open developer tools in most browsers. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript